# Jupyter notebook: How to \usepackage{} for LaTeX

Tags: latex, jupyter-notebook

I would like to know how I can `\usepackage{}` for LaTeX in Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure this is the only or even best way of doing it, but it seems to work. Write a template file ("mytemplate.tplx") in the same directory as your ipynb notebook file ("mynotebook.ipynb"). mytemplate.tplx looks like:

```
((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))

((* block packages *))
((( super() )))
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
((* endblock packages *))
```

Build your pdf LaTex file by executing the following:

```
jupyter nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to latex --template mytemplate.tplx
pdflatex mynotebook.tex
```

Comment: Could you add an example please. I'm not sure what you mean with the template file.

Comment: Note that this answer is for generating latex documents from ipython notebooks - it does not modify the way that jupyter notebook/jupyterlab renders markdown cells. As the answer states, this solution can be run using the command [`jupyter nbconvert --to latex`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#convert-latex) which is used for exporting .tex files.