# nbconvert latex output failing to link internal cells

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, latex, pdflatex, nbconvert

I have linked my cells internally in a Jupyter notebook, but when I try to convert the file to Latex using the command `jupyter nbconvert --to latex ta.ipynb --no-input'

I get the following errors in place of links

`Flag all Section??`

I have linked the sections using the following code:

`Flag all [non-billable courses](#non_billable)
  <a id="non_billable"></a>`

Comment: Did you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49547618/8508004) involving hyperref package? [This](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/11) suggests the issue was downstream but that is an old discussion.

Comment: it works, but not completely. It does not display all of my figures.

Comment: I figured it out. It is because of the style.hide_index() styler. Any idea how can I not display the indexes during ht output as a pdf?