# Latex Usepackages in Jupyter

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter-lab

I am trying to use Latex usepackages in Jupyter. There is a previous post that has some solution to it, but it is convoluted:
[Jupyter notebook: How to \usepackage{} for LaTeX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448200/jupyter-notebook-how-to-usepackage-for-latex)

A much better solution seems to be the following:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562924/how-to-add-latex-packages-to-markdown/

But the latter solution simply won't work. Mathjax environments work for me, using $ and $$, also \begin{equation} \end{equation} seems to work. But for example, \textit{} for italic text won't work.

The %%latex cell magic command does not improve things. There is no point in using it, because it allows just what the markdown cells allow by default.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Minimal example:

```
---
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{bbm}
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
---

$\bbm{1}$
```

According to the second source, this should produce the "1" symbol used for matrices. I'm certainly misunderstanding something here...but I don't understand how to do it differently.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? Are you hoping to add packages to the pdf export? Or do you want to add to markdown cells in an ipython notebook? Or is this some latex extension for jupyterlab? Please provide very specific goals, what you'd like to achieve, and what you've tried/where you're stuck.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Hi. I just want to use Latex usepackages in Jupyter. Like "bbm" for example. As I understand, that is possible and in the second link that I posted people seem to have had success with the approach described there. But when I use the posted code, it does not work.

Comment: "in jupyter" - can you explain what you mean exactly?

Comment: Jupyter-Lab. In an .ipython file. I just want to use Latex in a markdown cell.

Comment: Thanks! That's important clarification. I'm not an expert in jupyterlab markdown but I'm guessing the answer will be no, not without some plugin that changes the way jupyterlab displays notebook markdown calls. Markdown is not a fully featured latex engine. You can always embed html or images...

Comment: In the second link I posted, they got it running. I mean, I would add a comment, trying to ask this "Ross", but I have no reputation on there, so the only thing I could do, would be to ask the question again...ridiculous concept. Anyways, I ended up asking on here, because I thought it's more appropriate.

Comment: Ok - yeah I see that they're using latex in a way I've never seen before on jupyter. Cool! Can you post your exact code you're trying to use and what's not working? See the guide to creating a [MRE]. Note that this may be simply a discontinued feature of jupyterlab markdown, in which case an issue or question to their mailing list may be more likely to resolve this.

Comment: Hi again. I posted the example code in the post. Problem is that Jupyter just doesn't recognize what I'm giving it, and I'm pretty sure I'm doing something stupid here...but I just don't know what. This might simply be a misunderstanding, and these guys just use Jupyter as an editor to create .tex files.

Comment: You might have better luck on the jupyterlab mailing list